# k-uniform, k-regular set family. Prove there is a coloring that leave no member monochromatic.

Tags: combinatorics

Let F be a set family.

F is k-uniform: each member of F has k points.

F is also k-regular: every point occurs in exactly k members of F.

Show that for k $\geq$ 10 there is a way to color all the points with 2 colors such that no member of F is monochromatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=\bigcup F$. Color the points of $X$ randomly black and white, independently and with each color having probability $\frac12$ for each point. For $f\in F$ let $A_f$ be the event that $f$ is monochromatic; clearly $$\Pr(A_f)=\frac1{2^{k-1}}$$ for each $f\in F$. Construct a graph $G$ with vertex set $V(G)=F$ by making $\{f_0,f_1\}$ an edge of $G$ iff $f_0\cap f_1\ne\varnothing$: $E(G)=\big\{\{f_0,f_1\}\in[F]^2:f_0\cap f_1\ne\varnothing\big\}$. Fix $f\in F$; each of the $k$ elements of $f$ belongs to $k-1$ other members of $F$, so $\deg_G(f)\le k(k-1)$. Thus, if $d=\max\{\deg_G(f):f\in F\}$, we have

$$\frac1{4d}\ge\frac1{4k(k-1)}\ge\frac1{2^{k-1}}=\Pr(A_f)$$

for each $f\in F$, provided that $k\ge 10$. Now use the (unnumbered) lemma on page $616$ of Erdős & Lovász, *Problems and results on 3-chromatic hypergraphs and some related questions*, available as a PDF [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz_local_lemma#References). (It’s on the eighth page of the PDF.)

Comment: Brian, can you give me an example of what a regular set is? Also, a regular intersecting family?

Comment: @Luffy: Not without more context than that, I’m afraid.

Comment: A family $F$ of subsets of $X$ (where $X$ is an n-set) is regular if every point lies in a constant number $r$ of elements of $F$.

Comment: @Luffy: For $k=1,\ldots,n-1$ let $P_k=\{k,k+1\}$, and let $P_n=\{1,n\}$; then $\{P_k:k\in[n]\}$ is a $2$-regular family of $2$-subsets of $[n]$ (for $n\ge 3$). Another example is $\{[n]\setminus\{k\}:k\in[n]\}$; this is an $(n-1)$-regular family of $(n-1)$-subsets of $[n]$.